# Нет переводов для входящих уведомлений/сообщений

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника, уведомления

В маленьком окошке нет переводов для некоторых строк:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Добавил/утвердил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18611
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18615
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18621
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18625
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18616
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18661
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18662
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18663
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18617
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18618
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18631
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18623

Будет в следующей сборке. Текущая rev 2022.11.30.43067

Одну строчку не нашёл. Завёл баг на MSE: [Unable to translate "Change inbox filter"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384264/339911)

Comment: Хоть бы кто плюсанул, ну автор вопроса например

Comment: @VladD первый пошёл :)

Comment: Второй за труды :)